# How to write scope where one attribute is less than other?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I tried this one

```
scope :opened, lambda {       
  where("entries_count <= limit")
}
```

But I get an error:

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'limit)' at line 1: SELECT `shifts`.* FROM `shifts`  WHERE
>   (entries_count <= limit)

Comment: `where("entries_count <= #{self.table_name}.limit")` may work

Comment: Backtick-quoting `limit` would be another (MySQL-specific) option.

Answer (score -2):

Are both entries_count and limit active record attributes mapped to columns?

```
scope :opened, -> { where(:entries_count <= :limit }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get this with:

```
scope :opened, lambda { |limit| where("entries_count <= ?",  limit) }
```

or this way that is in a more updated syntax for lambda:

```
scope :opened, -> limit { where("entries_count <= ?",  limit) }
```

Comment: limit is a value taken from a column in the table, not an argument to the scope.